# Array.push does not work in $.each within $.getJSON

Tags: javascript

I have a `$.getJSON()` function set up like this.

```
var colNames = [];                 
$.getJSON(reqURL, function(data) {
 $.each(data.rows, function(key,val){
    var colName = val.column_name;
    colNames.push(colName);
 });
 console.log(colNames);
}));
console.log(colNames);
```

The `console.log()` outside the `$.getJSON()` function fires first, meaning `colNames` never gets filled.

What must I change so that `colNames` gets filled?

Comment: It's asynchronous. The `console.log`s are called before the function that you pass into `$.each` is called.

Comment: Drop `console.log(colName)` just right after you declare it and tell us what does it return.

Comment: @Kinduser The first one returns `colnames` all filled up. The second one returns an empty array.

Comment: @SumnerEvans has explained you why it happens this way.

Comment: I'm still not sure what to do after reading the other question

Comment: Since the `getJSON` function is **asynchronous**, the `console.log` function at the end of your code executes before it was finished (loaded). That's why it returns an empty array.

Comment: But I do not understand what I need to change to make the second `console.log()` print a filled `colNames`

Comment: Easiest but not really clever would be using timeout. `setTimeout(() => { console.log(colNames) }, 1000)`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without `setTimeout()`?

Comment: @Username What you need to do is to understand that the values will never be available until the callback you passed to `$.getJSON()` gets invoked and anything that is dependent on these values has to be deferred to that callback. In other words, there's nothing you can do to make the data available at the point of your second `console.log()`, that would require time travel.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm How would I set up the code to do that?

Comment: @Username In a way you're already doing it. Your first `console.log()` is inside the callback function where the data is available. Anything you need to do with the data has to be done at that point.